# Set up Heroku log drain on worker process?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I set up a log drain for my Heroku app that drains the logs via HTTPS.

I added it to my app with this toolbelt command:

```
heroku drains:add http://example.com --app MY_APP
```

Trouble is I have a chron job that runs on a separate dyno, my worker process, and that isn't draining.

I really only want to drain the logs from the worker process.

Is there a way to add a drain to ONLY the worker process?  Barring that, is there a way to make it so the worker process is included in the drain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At this point in time it seems not possible to filter a drain on anything.

The drain contains ALL logging from the specified app and all dynos in that app.

the only fix right now seems to be using a filter on the receiving end.